# how to convert multiple row data into array and subtract it from another array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, arraylist

I am fetching multiple rows from my data base like,

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM student_info where district = '".$admdistrict."' AND user_status = 'approved' ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$delete = mysql_fetch_array($resultt);
$std_delete_array = explode(',', $delete['id']);
```

the value of `id` in database is like 4,5,6 in different rows but it is giving only first value 4.
Another array I am fetching is,

```
$query="SELECT * FROM events where id='$district'";
$showdata=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$user=mysql_fetch_array($showdata);
$std_fulllist_array = explode(',', $user['std_list']);
```

the value in database is 4,5,6,8. But in single coloumn, so it is giving proper output. now I want to subtract `$std_delete_array` from `$std_fulllist_array`.
I am using following **code**,

```
$values = array_diff($std_fulllist_array, $std_delete_array);
```

which is only subtracting first value of `$std_delete` array.

strucutre of table student_info  is 
id  ! name ! District
4     a      panipat
5     b      panipat
6     c      panipat

strucutre of table events is 
id  ! district     !       std_list
1      panipat             4,5,6
2      karnal              4,7,8
3      chandigarh          5,6,7

Comment: Try printing `$delete['id']` and check it is holding expected value...

Comment: "_but it is giving only first value 4_", you need to work on your first query, which is not working as you expect.

Comment: i know problem is in first query but dont know how to fetch all values

Comment: if you can share structure of table, then we might be able to help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying **the value of id in database is like 4,5,6 in different rows**
that means your table is look like

```
id district
-- ---------
4  abc
5  def
6  geh
8  ijk
```

so your first query is fetching multiple records.

**EDIT**

So your query would be

```
$ret_ = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM student_info where district = '".$admdistrict."' AND user_status = 'approved' ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['id'];
        $ret_[] = $row;  
    }
}
print_r($ret_);
```

Comment: you need to loop you result in while loop

Comment: i also tried it but dont know how to add it in array so i can subtract it from $std_fulllist_array

Comment: did you got your result ?

Comment: i am aplying your code .. can i use $ret_ direct in $values = array_diff($std_fulllist_array, $ret_);

Comment: print_r($ret_);  output is Array ( )

Comment: Yoges refer these sites for array_diff and for fetching results http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp